# Spring JmsTemplate split large file

Tags: spring, ibm-mq

Is there a way to split large message payloads and send through Spring JmsTemplate?

IBM MQ supports splitting large payloads via properties JMSX_GROUPID, JMS_IBM_LAST_MSG_IN_GROUP yet there seems to be now way (could not find any resources) of how to send large files over JMS.

My queue max size is set at 4Mb, and I have to send messages of over 100Mb as a ByteMessage.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working by using different properties name as following:

JMSXGroupID
JMSXGroupSeq
JMS_IBM_Last_Msg_In_Group

Header of the messages is properly setup.